# Deploy External Library on Nexus using Maven

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I'm using Maven & Nexus repository.

The setup looks good, my project deploy on Nexus properly, but I would like to add my External library loaded by Maven as well on Nexus and I don't find the way to do it.

Do you know how to do it ?

Many thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by External libraries?

Comment: Do you mean uploading the jars in the classpath onto nexus alongwith your compiled artifact/jar ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deploy an external library you can use the Maven goal [`deploy:deploy-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html).

I took the following example from the [Nexus 3 support](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115006744008-How-can-I-programmatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-3-)

On the command line this could look like this:

`mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.somecompany -DartifactId=project -Dversion=1.0.0 -DgeneratePom=true -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=nexus -Durl=http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases -Dfile=target/project-1.0.0.jar`

The `repositoryId` is a server defined in your `settings.xml`.

```
<servers>
...
  <server>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <username>deployment</username>
      <password>deployment123</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Hint: As this is a bit cumbersome. Check if your library is available on a public Maven repository. If it is available just add that repository to Nexus as [Proxy Maven Repository](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/maven-repositories#MavenRepositories-ProxyingMavenRepositories).

Comment: Thanks for your help